Ubuntu 24.04 crashed - can‘t find wifi settings after force restart
Problems from the last crash：
Ubuntu 24.04 crashed - unable to automount SSD after force restart
Due to a problem with my capture card, I couldn't get the display and I used a physical shutdown.
I moved the system disk to another computer and this time I couldn't find the wifi Settings.
I tried
sudo dmesg  to investigate hardware driver issues
sudo lshw -C network to query network driver
Finally, the problem was then resolved by reinstalling the driver.
dpkg -s build-essential
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo dpkg -i 【network-driver】.deb

I am curious why the NIC driver is lost after an abnormal shutdown?
System Details Report
Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-20 09:11:47

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B760M D2H DDR4
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   12th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-12400F × 12
Graphics:                                    NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3050
D#isk Capacity:                               2.0 TB

Software Information:

F#irmware Version:                            F1
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-49-generic

